# librsvg-2.so.2: undefined reference to `cairo_tag_begin'

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ros

I recently use ROS system to do some experiment in my new laptop. And My operating system is Ubuntu 20.04. bty the ROS system version is noetic. Then the strange thing happened. I can successfully compile my rospackage which is code in c++ on my old machine, but I got this error on my new laptop.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AqRG.png)

I google the question and get no solution. Can anyone help me with this, It's beyond what I can do.

Comment: please don't post images of errors. Also provide a [mre]. At a guess you need to link to the cairo libraries